# Not able to display content in html ,which is in javascript DOM

Tags: html, setattribute

**JavaScript part**

```js
var popoverTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="popover"]'));
        var popoverList = popoverTriggerList.map(function (popoverTriggerEl) {
        return new bootstrap.Popover(popoverTriggerEl,{
            html: true
          })
        });
        document.getElementById("popcart").setAttribute('data-bs-content', '<h5>Cart for your items in my shopping cart</h5>');
```

**HTML part**

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary cart mx-2" id="popcart" data-bs-toggle="popover" title="Your cart"  data-bs-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?">
          Cart(<span id="cart">0</span>)
```

I was trying to show `<h5>` content which is in JavaScript in `data-bs-content` in HTML

Comment: Your code is unreadable. Please read the formatting help around and linked from the question editor. Better yet, use the [stack snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) feature which comes with an autoformat button.

Comment: As @Quentin mentioned, using stack snippets would be great here. I  added basic formatting to your post to make it at least readable. Please edit your question to explain the problem you are having and what you have done to try to fix it in a bit more detail as it is still pretty vague

Comment: You have Bootstrap in there... Please at least mention that, and add the corresponding tag/tags. If it's not relevant, please remove it from the code. See [mre].

Answer (score 0):

When you create `popoverTriggerList` you set the values contained therein at that point. If you move the call to modify the dataset attribute to before that it will work.

```js
document.getElementById("popcart").setAttribute('data-bs-content', '<h5>Cart for your items in my shopping cart</h5>');

var popoverTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="popover"]'));
var popoverList = popoverTriggerList.map(function(popoverTriggerEl) {
  return new bootstrap.Popover(popoverTriggerEl, {
    html: true
  })
});
```

```html
<link href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>


<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary cart mx-2" id="popcart" data-bs-toggle="popover" title="Your cart" data-bs-content="And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. Right?">
    Cart(<span id="cart">0</span>)
</button>
```